# Pass object along with object method to function

Tags: python, class, object, parameters

I know that in Python that if, say you want to pass two parameters to a function, one an object, and another that specifies the instance method that must be called on the object, the user can easily pass the object itself, along with the name of the method (as a string) then use the `getattr` function on the object and the string to call the method on the object.

Now, I want to know if there is a way (as in C++, for those who know) where you pass the object, as well as the actual method (or rather a reference to the method, but not the method name as a string). An example:

```
def func(obj, method):
    obj.method();
```

I have tried passing it as follows:

```
func(obj, obj.method)
```

or as

```
func(obj, classname.method)
```

but neither works (the second one I know was a bit of a long shot, but I tried it anyway)

I know that you can also just define a function that just accepts the method, then call it as

```
func2(obj.method)
```

but I am specifically asking about instances where you want a reference to the object itself, as well as a *reference* to a desired class instance (not static) method to be called on the object.

EDIT:

For those that are interested, I found quite an elegant way 'inspired' by the accepted answer below. I simply defined `func` as

```
def func(obj, method):
     #more code here
     method(obj, parameter);     #call method on object obj
```

and called it as

```
func(obj_ref, obj_class.method);
```

where obj_class is the actual class that obj_ref is an instance of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A method is just a function with the first parameter bound to an instance. As such you can do things like.

```
# normal_call 
result = "abc".startswith("a")

# creating a bound method 
method = "abc".startswith
result = method("a") 

# using the raw function 
function = str.startswith
string = "abc"
result = function(string, "a")
```

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer! See the edit above for what I came up with following up with your answer. Discovering more and more what an elegant language Python really is.

Answer (score 0):

you can search getattr

```
def apiroute(self, apiname, request):
    try:
        if callable(getattr(self,apiname)):
            return  getattr(self,apiname)(request)
        else:
            return "action is not a method"
    except:
        return "action is not exists"
```